# SQL. Создание связей

Tags: sql

Помогите разобраться. Как с помощью SQL установить связь между таблицами:

- один к одному;
- один к многим;
- много к многим;

Comment: Это же азы. Нагуглить за вас книги где это всё объясняется?

Comment: **1.** просто id из одной таблицы в колонке другой таблицы. один к одному можно обеспечить уникальностью на требуемую колонку в обоих таблицах. **2.** так же как в 1 случае, но без уникальности в таблице где "много" записей. **3.** отдельная таблица с двумя полями id из 1й таблицы и id из 2й. primary key содержит обе колонки

Comment: @Mike а можно маленький пример, если вам не трудно? пункт № 3 понял.не совсем понял пункт №1 и №2

Comment: @Mike если я вас правильно понял, связи это уровень теории..на уровне SQL это обьясняется CONSTRAINT ,благодаря которому мы устанавливаем FOREIGN KEY ? если нам нужна связь 1 к 1: то мы устанавливаем  FOREIGN KEY в обоих таблицах; если 1 к многим то таблица которая будем иметь много записей относящихня к 1 записи другой таблицы - мы в ней создаем  FOREIGN KEY первой таблицы?

Comment: все 3 вида связи обеспечиваются foreign key. вопрос лишь в уникальности колонки в той таблице, которая ссылается. В основной таблице колонка на которую ссылаются обязана быть primary key, так что она уникальна. Вот 2й таблице если сделаем колонку так же primary key или построим unqie index - то связь будет 1к1 т.к. ни в одну из таблиц невозможно положить один и тот же id 2 раза. Если уникальности нет - то 1-многие. И да, в ссылающейстя таблице делаем foreign. Для связи Многие-Многие в связующей таблице соответственно два foreign смотрящие на разные таблицы

Answer (score 1):

Например есть таблица пользователь с уникальным ID 

`таблица 1 пользователь 
id primary key`

есть вторая таблица с внешнем ключом на 1-ю таблицу

`таблица2 направление
user_id FOREIGN KEY на id  1 таблицы
Должность ...и т.д.`

данный пример связи 1 к 1

одной записи из 1 таблицы будет соответствовать 1 запись из второй

связь 1 ко многим  например нам нужно хранить какие задачи назначены на пользователе первая таблица без изменений 

`таблица 3 работы`

`work_ID primary key
user_id FOREIGN KEY на id  1 таблицы`

1 пользователю могут быть назначены несколько заданий

связь многие ко многим например нам нужно хранить  оборудование записанное для конкретного пользователя первая таблица без изменений, 
добавляем две новые таблицы таблицу  с перечнем оборудования

`таблица 4 оборудование`

`device_ID primary key
Name .....`

и таблицу со связью пользователя с оборудованием

`таблица 5 Перечень оборудования`

`user_ID FOREIGN KEY из 1 таблицы`

`device_ID FOREIGN KEY из 4 таблицы`